# Google drive api Files: get doesn't list full metadata

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried using the example get method on the google drive api documentation, however what is returned is not the full metadata of the file, only this:

```
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "1vbLiXALYOYoVev1KD_ajVBfh5_CgvGgP",
  "name": "3.png",
  "mimeType": "image/png",
  "result": {
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "1vbLiXALYOYoVev1KD_ajVBfh5_CgvGgP",
    "name": "3.png",
    "mimeType": "image/png"
  }
}
```

What should appear is something with many more fields:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1vbLiXALYOYoVev1KD_ajVBfh5_CgvGgP",
 "etag": "\"MTU4Njg3NTU3MjUxOQ\"",
 "selfLink": "",
 "webContentLink": "",
 "alternateLink": "",
 "embedLink": "",
 "iconLink": "",
 "thumbnailLink": "",
 "title": "3.png"
// ... and so on
```

I get the full response when I use the "try api" screen on the api docs, but not when calling it from javascript:

```
function printFile(fileId) {
    appendPre(fileId)
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      'fileId': fileId
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2))
    });
  }
```

I used the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope, which is listed as a scope sufficient for the request to be completed. Help!

Answer (score 3):

How about this modification?

At Drive API V3, when `fields` property is not used, a part of fields is returned. So in your case, for example, you can retrieve other parameters using `fields: "*"`. When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
  'fileId': fileId
});
```

#### To:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
  'fileId': fileId,
  'fields': "*"  // Added
});
```

#### Reference:

- [Parameters of Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#parameters)

Comment: Still the same thing!

Comment: @Ivan Zabrodin Thank you for replying. About `Still the same thing!`, unfortunately, in my environment, when `'fields': "*"` is added, the values, which are different from the result that `'fields': "*"` is not added, are retrieved. I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So can you provide whole script for replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: No, this won't work. I've tried setting the fields to "downloadUrl", which is the value I actually want. One time when I tried to use this in google's "try api" part of the documentation, everything worked fine, but when i signed out and the signed back in, the problem manifested when using "try api" as well as in my own application. Could this be because of some permissions at some level not being granted?

Comment: @Ivan Zabrodin Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `No, this won't work`, can I ask you about the detail of it? Unfortunately, from `No, this won't work`, I cannot understand about your current situation. Because in my environment, when I tested above script, all fields are returned. So can you provide whole script for replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. By the way, about "Try this API", when you don't log in Google account, it cannot be used. Please be careful this.

Comment: Hm.. This seems to be some setting that I wrongly assigned somewhere during the app's creation. I think I'll try again with a new api project and everything.

Comment: @Ivan Zabrodin Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that above modified script worked. So about the script, please don't worry.