# Can an app check if a file as write access with the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

My application can create (load) and write (save) files in Google Drive, providing the adequate scopes are granted by the user.

However, there is one case that I can't resolve. If a user grants the scope for accessing files created **by the application** ***and*** the scope for **all files read only**, I suppose that means the application can get all files from the Drive, but only write those created by the app itself.

I don't know, then, how the app can check when loading a Drive file (getting it) if that given file has been created by the app or not -- or in other words, if the app has write access on it.
The only way I know to find it out is to try to write the file anyway and deal with the request error response. But I don't like it because it would make more sense for the app to already prevent saving from the moment we know that file cannot be written...

I'm aware there are ways to query the permissions for a while with the Google API ([here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221-42LgoSWRwK-gPqGlYe8ekETBg4vipCO%22%2C%22permissionId%22%3A%2210466420164354936322%22%7D)), but that only gives back a very shallow returned value that doesn't help me at all (I'd get the same for a file created by the app than one that hasn't).

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check if the app created the file. With the Google Drive API v3, there were 2 things I needed to do to be able to check -- so I'll list them here if that helps anyone else in the future.

First, when I load the file in the application, to get every fields of the meta data, use `alt="json"` **and** use the parameter `fields` to get more details that what is returned otherwise. For example using `fields="*"`. This was indicated on [this ticket.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276598/google-drive-api-files-get-doesnt-list-full-metadata)

Second, the field to check for knowing if the application created the file in Drive is called `isAppAuthorized`, as described in the [File object documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files#File).